# In Azure Stream Analytics Bad Request results when calling Azure Machine Learning function even though Azure ML service is called fine from C#

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-stream-analytics

We have an Azure Machine Learning web service that is called fine from a C# program.  And it works fine when called as an HTML post (with Headers and a JSON string in the body).  However, in Azure Stream Analytics you have to create a Function to call an ML service.  And when this function is called in ASA, it fails with Bad Request.

The documentation for the ML service gives the following documentation:

Request Body
Sample Request

```
{
   "Inputs":{
      "input":[
         {
            "device":"60-1-94-49-36-c5",
            "uid":"5f4736aabfc1312385ea09805cc922",
            "weight":"9-9-9-9-9-8-9-8-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-8-9-9-8-8-9-9-9-9-9- 
9-9-9-9-9-9-9-8-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-8-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9- 
9-9-8-9-9-9-9-8-9-9-9-8-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-8-9-9-9-9-8-8-16-16-15-16-16-15- 
15-16-15-15-15-15-16-15-15-16-15-15-9-15-15-15-15-15-15-15-9-15-16-15-15-9- 
15-16-16-16-15-15-15-15-15-15-15-15-16-16-15-9-15-15-15-16-15-16-15-15-15- 
15-15-16-15-15-16-16-15-15-15"
         }
      ]
   },
   "GlobalParameters":{

   }
}
```

The Azure Stream Analytics function (that calls the ML service above) has this signature:

```
FUNCTION SIGNATURE
SmartStokML2018Aug17 ( device NVARCHAR(MAX) , 
                       uid    NVARCHAR(MAX) , 
                       weight NVARCHAR(MAX) ) RETURNS RECORD
```

Here the function is expecting 3 string arguments and NOT a full JSON string.  The 3 parameters are strings (NVARCHAR as shown).

The 3 parameters have been passed in: device, uid and weight.  And in different string formats.  This includes passing the string arguments as JSON strings, using JSON.stringify() in a UDF, or sending in arguments with just data, no headers ("device", "uid", "weight").  But all calls to the ML service fail.

```
WITH QUERY1 AS ( 
SELECT DEVICE, UID, WEIGHT, 
       udf.jsonstringify( concat('{"device": "',try_cast(device as nvarchar(max)), '"}')) jsondevice,
       udf.jsonstringify( concat('{"uid": "',try_cast(uid as nvarchar(max)), '"}')) jsonuid,
       udf.jsonstringify( concat('{"weight": "',try_cast(weight as nvarchar(max)), '"}')) jsonweight
FROM iothubinput2018aug21 ),

QUERY2 AS (
SELECT IntellistokML2018Aug21(JSONDEVICE, JSONUID, JSONWEIGHT) AS RESULT
FROM QUERY1
)

SELECT *    
INTO OUT2BLOB20                
FROM QUERY2
```

Most of the errors are:
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\" {weight:9'\n\r\n\r\n

> > In what format does the ML Service expect these parameters to be passed in?

Note: the queries have been tried with ASA Compatibility Level 1 and 1.1.

Comment: The reason that we started trying to format the arguments as JSON - before sending to the ML Service - is because we are getting an error back from ML Service: **KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'**.  This error does not occur when the ML Service is called from C# code.

Answer (score 0):

In an ASA function, you don't need to construct the JSON input to Azure ML yourself. You just specify your event fields directly. Eg:

WITH QUERY1 AS (
SELECT IntellistokML2018Aug21(DEVICE, UID, WEIGHT) AS RESULT
FROM iothubinput2018aug21
)

SELECT *
INTO OUT2BLOB20
FROM QUERY1

Comment: The reason that we started trying to format the arguments as JSON - before sending to the ML Service - is because we are getting an error back from ML Service: **KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'**.  This error does not occur when the ML Service is called from C# code.

Comment: Can you please share some sample input and your C# code that you are using to call Azure ML?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Dushyant post, you don't need to construct the JSON input for Azure ML. However, I've noticed that your input is in a nested JSON with Array, so you need to extract the field in your first step.

Here an example:

```
WITH QUERY1 AS(
SELECT  
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(inputs.input,0),'device') as device,
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(inputs.input,0),'uid') as uid,
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(inputs.input,0),'weight') as weight
FROM iothubinput2018aug21 )
```

Please note that if you can have several messages in the "Inputs.input" array, you can use CROSS APPLY to read all of them (in my example I only assumed there is one).

More information on querying JSON here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json

Let us know if it works for you.

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)

Comment: The issue may be that the ML Service is expecting Inpus.Input.uid, Inputs.Input.weight  i.e. nested values to match this JSON format:
`{
   "Inputs":{
      "input":[
         {
            "device":"60-c5",
            "uid":"5f422",
            "weight":"9--15"
         }
      ]
   },
   "GlobalParameters":{
   }
}`
However, the current devices are sending the JSON in a flatened format: `{ "did":"8266","device":"5c-fd","uid": "5f42", "weight": "122-21" }`.  Hence, no need for inputs.input in query.  **But why would this cause the ML Svc to fail - the ML params are the same?**

Comment: I talked to the data scientist.  The ML Service requires exactly this nested json input format. And exactly means absolutely same and not only the key value pairs wrapped in a json object.  **So does ASA send the parameters as JSON formated - as ML service expects??** : `{
   "Inputs":{
      "input":[
         {
            "device":"60-1-94-49-36-c5",
            "uid":"5f47c922",
            "weight":"9-15-15"
         }
      ]
   },
   "GlobalParameters":{

   }
}`

Comment: I want to highlight that ASA formats the JSON input so the Azure Machine Learning function can consume it directly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the ML Service is expecting devices with a KNOWN Mac ID.  If a device is passed in with an UNKNOWN MAC ID, then there is a failure in the Python script.  This should be handled more gracefully.

Now there are errors related to batch processing of rows:

```
"Error": "- Condition 'The number of events in Azure ML request ID 0 is 28 but the 
number of results in the response is 1. These should be equal. The Azure ML model 
is  expected to score every row in the batch call and return a response for it.' 
should not be false in method 
'Microsoft.Streaming.CalloutProcessor.dll 
!Microsoft.Streaming.Processors.Callout.AzureMLRRS.ResponseParser.Parse' 
(Parse at offset 69 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0\r\n)\r\n",

"Message": "An error was encountered while calling the Azure ML web service. An 
error occurred when parsing the Azure ML web service response. Please check your 
Azure ML web service and data model., - Condition 'The number of events in Azure ML 
request ID 0 is 28 but the number of results in the response is 1. These should be 
equal. The Azure ML model is expected to score every row in the batch call and 
return a response for it.' should not be false in method 

'Microsoft.Streaming.CalloutProcessor.dll 
!Microsoft.Streaming.Processors.Callout.AzureMLRRS.ResponseParser.Parse' (Parse at 
 offset 69 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0\r\n)\r\n, : 
 OutputSourceAlias:query2Callout;",
 Type": "CallOutProcessingFailure",
 "Correlation ID": "2f87188e-1eda-479c-8e86-e2c4a827c6e7"
```

I am looking into this article for guidance:
[Scale your Stream Analytics job with Azure Machine Learning functions][1]: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-scale-with-machine-learning-functions.md

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to add a comment to the original thread regarding this so replying here:
"The number of events in Azure ML 
request ID 0 is 28 but the number of results in the response is 1. These should be 
equal"

ASA's call out to Azure ML is modeled as a scalar function. This means that every input event needs to generate exactly one output. In your case, seems that you are generating one output for 28 input events. Can you modify your logic to generate an output per input event?

Comment: The default batch size from ASA to an ML Function is 1000.  When I changed that to 1, the ML Function can be called successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the JSON format:
{ "Inputs":{ "input":[ { "device":"60-c5", "uid":"5f422", "weight":"9--15" } ] }, "GlobalParameters":{ } }

All the extra markup will be added by ASA when calling AML. Do you have a way of inspecting the input received by your AML web service? For eg, modify your model code to write to blob.

Answer (score 0):

AML calls are expected to follow scalar semantics - one output per input.